# Можно ли перевернуть строку без циклов и встроенных методов

Tags: java, рекурсия

Сегодня получил список тестов на вакансию и некоторые показались крайне интересными

1. Реализовать метод reverse, на входе String, нельзя использовать циклы и встроенные методы.
2. Реализовать метод для суммирования чисел, на вход получаем Integer, например 1235, необходимо вернуть сумму 1 + 2 + 3 + 5, не используя циклы и операции со строками

Comment: Ну, рекурсия, очевидно

Comment: В обоих случаях можно использовать `StringBuilder`. Для первого случая есть готовый метод, а для второго делаем `int sum = stringBuilder.chars() .map(c -> Character.digit(c, 10)) .sum()`

Comment: Вам не кажется, что вопрос содержит два вопроса?

Answer (score 3):

Как правило, если в задании написано сделать что-либо, не используя циклы, это скорее всего толстый намёк на использование рекурсии.
Однако, остаётся открытым вопрос *использования встроенных методов*, так как в джаве "прямой" доступ к символам строки типа индекса (как в C# `char c = str[0];`) невозможен и необходимо пользоваться как минимум методами `String::charAt` / `String::substring` / `String::toCharArray` для доступа к символам/подстрокам.  Поэтому предположим, что "табу" накладывается только на методы типа `StringBuilder::reverse`.
Также не будем рассматривать вариант использования Stream API.

Сразу же следует заметить, что рекурсия конечно божественна, но для достаточно больших входных данных (например, длинных строк) вероятность переполнения стека вызовов и выбрасывания `StackOverflowError` стремится к единице.

1. Переворот строки.
   a) C использованием `String::charAt` и `String::substring`:

```java
public static String reverseSub(String str) {
    // фильтрация входных данных / выход из рекурсии
    if (null == str || "".equals(str)) {
        return str;
    }
    return reverseSub(str.substring(1)) + str.charAt(0);
}
```

Основной недостаток такого решения -- множественная генерация подстрок и конкатенация с одиночным символом.

б) С использованием одного массива символов и перестановкой элементов в начале и конце массива:

```java
public static String reverse(String str) {
    if (null == str || "".equals(str)) {
        return str;
    }
    return new String(reverse(str.toCharArray(), 0, str.length()));
}

private static char[] reverse(char[] arr, int start, int end) {
    if (start >= end) {
        return arr;
    }
    // перестановка символов в конце и начале массива
    char tmp = arr[start];
    arr[start++] = arr[--end];
    arr[end] = tmp;

    return reverse(arr, start, end);
}
```

2. Вычисление суммы цифр числа
   Это более тривиальная задача, которая решается при помощи целочисленного деления и остатка при делении на 10:

```java
public static int sumDigits(int n) {
    if (n < 0) return sumDigits(-n);

    return n < 1 ? n : n % 10 + sumDigits(n / 10);
}

System.out.println(sumDigits(123456)); // -> 21
```

*(Обновление)* Если в качестве входного значения допускается `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, для которого не существует противоположного положительного целого значения, то следует обработать этот случай особо:

```java
public static int sumDigits(int n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        if (n == Integer.MIN_VALUE)
            return 1 + sumDigits(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        return sumDigits(-n);
    }
    return n < 1 ? n : n % 10 + sumDigits(n / 10);
}

System.out.println(sumDigits(Integer.MIN_VALUE)); // -> 47
```

Comment: `sumDigits` для Integer.MIN_VALUE будет возращать его же.  Можно это решить добавив перегруженный метод с параметром типа` long` и в нём считать сумму.  А в `int sumDigits(int n)` будет только `return (int) sumDigits((long) n);`

Comment: @siarhei987, Исправил без расширения типа